# structure solution outputpath by project

Tags: msbuild, projects-and-solutions

I'm building a visual studio solution with msbuild

```
msbuild.exe my.sln
```

This way it outputs everything to the output paths specified in each project (bin\ by default), but in this case I need all the output artefacts to be in different folder, used for packaging. If I run

```
msbuild.exe my.sln /p:OutputhPath=<someFolder>
```

Then all the artifacts will end up in the specified folder, but the structure will be flat. What I would like it to be, is:

```
\package
    \project1
    \project2
    ...
```

But I can't think of a good way to do this, without modifying individual project files (which is almost out of question). Any ideas? (msbuild 4.0, VS2010 - if that changes anything)

Comment: Thanks for a downvote, whoever that was. The solution will probably be to run a powershell script to modify project files, then build them and then undo the modifications - it seems there's just no way of doing this with just MSBuild

Comment: Some people are just odd aren't they.  I think this is a good question.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better way, but one thing you could do is build in place with `msbuild.exe my.sln`, and then copy the outputs to your `\package` dir so you keep the hierarchy. It should be pretty simple to do. You can use this as a starting point:

```
<Target Name="Package">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SourceFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\src</SourceFolder>
      <TargetFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\package</TargetFolder>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToCopy Include="$(SourceFolder)\**\bin\Debug\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Recursive copy w/o flattening folder structure: -->
    <Copy 
        SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" 
        DestinationFiles="@(FilesToCopy->'$(TargetFolder)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
      />
  </Target>
```

You can also define a property to keep track of your build configuration, and replace the hardcoded `bin\Debug` with `bin\$(BuildConfig)`.

Comment: A good idea, but %(RecursiveDir) will give me the full path, not only the project name - and in my case that might be a pretty long path.

Comment: %(RecursiveDir) should only give the part that matches the wildcard (**), so if your projects are all directly under the src\ folder, you would just get the project name. If you have a different folder structure maybe you can use string functions to modify the meta properties. See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx

Comment: Sadly, the projects are not directly under src folder

Comment: Right, that was just an example, you are meant to change it to suit how your own code is structured. Good luck.

Comment: And the problem is, that sadly, there's no way to adopt your example to a project structure, where all projects are not directly under src folder.

Comment: That doesn't matter. ItemGroup can represent any set of files, even if they don't have a common direct or indirect parent folder.